# SQL get connection between ID's

Tags: mysql, sql, join

We have that datatable:

```
id | parent_id

124    510

124    407

125    504

126    508
```

I want result that returns 407 as a child of 510:

```
id | childOfparent_id | parent_id 

124    407       510
125    NULL      504
126    NULL      508
```

How can I achive that? I tried with grouping by id and counting distnict values but with no sucess.

Child has a lower id value: 4xx is lower than 5xx. I'm using mysql.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: But how are we supposed to know who's the parent, and who's the child?

Comment: Child has a lower id value: 4xx is lower than 5xx.

Comment: And if there are another row with id 124, with value 444? And one single row with id 125?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`, lowest value for child, highest for parent:

```
select id, min(parent_id) as childOfparent_id, max(parent_id) as parent_id
from tablename
group by id
having min(parent_id) <> max(parent_id)
```

You can also do a self `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.id, t2.parent_id as childOfparent_id, t1.parent_id as parent_id
from tablename t1
  left join tablename t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.parent_id > t2.parent_id
```

In the case no child exists, `NULL` will be returned.

Comment: This sql returns same childOfParent and parent_id.

Comment: That will happen only for id's with only one row/person, which you said won't happen.

Comment: Alright, I have now adjusted the GROUP BY with a HAVING clause. Try again, and do also test the JOIN version.

Comment: Both of sql works. Can you modify join statement that will return results as you se in my edited post? I tried right join, but results weren't the same as my whises.

Comment: I'll adjust the join, will be up in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (Id int,parent_id int)

insert into @t(Id,parent_id) values (124,510),(124,407)
;with CTE AS (
select Id,parent_id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ID)R from @t)
select T.Id,T.parent_id,TT.parent_id As ChildId from 
(
Select ID,parent_id from CTE where R = 1)T,(
Select ID,parent_id from CTE where R = 2)TT
```